# B2B handling SOAP Message but there is no response

Tags: ibm-datapower, b2b

Dears,
I developed my first `datapower` `b2b` solution, it must handle `soap` messages, the sender is sending soap message and the `b2b` service must retrieve soap also.
and I did the following :

1. I created an external Profile `ExternalParter_hub` and internal Partner `IntrenalPartner_hub`.
2. I set the `destination` for `IntrenalPartner_hub` to `soap` web service as a back-end.
3. `IntrenalPartner_hub` I made the response type `SOAP`.
4. I created `B2BGW` service and i added the Profiles above and i created `HTTP Front Side handler` for it.
5. In the `B2BGW` service that i created , i used the `Document Routing Preprocessor` in `Advanced` tab and I set the `xsl` document to assign `sender` and `reciever` data.
6. I created `MPGW` service and routes to the B2BGW service.

   I tested the `service` using `soapui` by calling `MPGW` url as endpoint,
   the `soapui` response panel is empty and the header section tells me that everything is ok. When Opening `debug probe` it tells that the soap service returns success soap message...
   but `MPGW service` doesn't recieves any response from `B2BGW service`!!
   and `B2B Transaction Viewer` show that message result is success ??

what is the missing part !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The B2BGW in DataPower can't return any Response data other than its own "signals", eg. AS2 MDN or ebMS receipts.

You have to either create/fetch your Response data in the MPGW "proxy" and attach that as the Result to the HTTP 200 Response from the B2BGW or use a url-open() (XSLT or GWS) in the Response (server-to-client) rule of the internal B2B partner.

So, there is no missing part, only a limitation in DataPower B2BGW...